# Hi, I am kind of confused, I was just playing around with gdb in linux and I ran into this

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, terminal, gdb

My question is, what does the number represent when I asked the debugger to represent the elements in the array? I know that it cant be ASCII, or binary representation of 5, is it the memory location of the specific int 5?

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at ArrnLoops.c:5

5     int  num[] = {5,15,25,45};

(gdb) display i
1: i = 2981876
(gdb) display num

2: num = {1466917, 1176192, 0, 134513753}
```

Comment: Do you mean the `5`/`1: `/`2: ` or the `2981876`, `1466917`, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's showing the contents. Remember that when you break on line 5, line 5 has not executed yet, so the initialization has not occurred. It's showing you whatever random value is currently at those memory locations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by `int 5`. Where did `5` come from?

I would guess that what you see is simply the current content of the array `num`.

The execution stopped at the definition of `num`, where memory for `num` already exists, but initialization has not been performed yet. So, what you see is garbage values in `num`.

If you step to the next line and display `num` again, you will see `{5,15,25,45}`.

The same probably applies to `i`, although it is impossible to see from what you posted where `i` is defined.

Comment: I figured `int 5` meant the first element of his array.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not the memory locations. They are called Garbage Values.Until an array element is not explicitly assigned it contains a garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at ArrnLoops.c:5

5     int  num[] = {5,15,25,45};
```

The `5` at the beginning of the line is the line number. If you <kbd>s</kbd>tep or go <kbd>n</kbd>ext, you'll see the line number for that command.

On the `display` commands, the `n:` is just a result tracking number. I haven't been able to figure out how to use it directly in other expressions, but if you use `print` (`p`) instead, you will see something like:

```
(gdb) p i
$1 = 2981876
```

Then you can use the result in other expressions:

```
(gdb) p $1 / 100
$2 = 29818
```